# OData V2 query to get null date records in filter

Tags: apache-camel, odata, sap-cpi

I am writing OData V2 query to get records from SAP SuccessFactors using SAP CPI. One of the filter criteria for me is to get the employees records with no "Actual Return Date". That field coming as this -  `<actualReturnDate/>` if there is no value in that field.

I am not able to query to check  as this is a date filed and blank. I cannot write `$filter=actualReturnDate eq ''` (as it is not string so it is looking for date type). I am not able to write `$filter=actualReturnDate eq datetime'${0000-00-00 00}'` (it says month cannot be blank).
I am not able to write `$filter=actualReturnDate eq datetime'${property.nullDate}'` by assigning "null" to nullDate (it says null cannot be a date).

Any thoughts on how write the OData query filter to get the records with `<actualReturnDate/>` ?

Thank you.